# How to give a number describing a "kilometer per hour speed limit"?

Tags: translation

How can I talk about speed limits in Chinese?
For example, how would I say, "That road has a 50 mile-per-hour speed limit?

Comment: By the way [公里](https://youdao.com/w/公里) is kilometer [like in the title] and [英里](https://youdao.com/w/英里) is mile [like in the main text].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, for the example you provided, you may say `那条路限速50英里` then I will know it is 50 miles/hour

secondly, in China the default unit is kilometers per hour for speed limit, so if you want to say "that road has a 50 km/h speed limit" you can just say `那条路限速50`

Comment: If OP is uncomfortable with this, 那条路限速一小时50英里 would also be perfectly grammatical, if a bit longer.

Comment: @YiFan, right, grammatically, if a word to word translation is needed, 一小时 need to be included somewhere. My answer is more commonly used when people communicate.